# Android Studio "Cannot resolve symbol XXX" on basic Android tutorial

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing the entry level tutorial on the official Android docs. I'm currently at this step where I'm creating the second activity:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

The problem I'm seeing is in creating the new activity when I have to give it a hierarchical parent in the New Activities popup. I enter the name of the parent (com.juannerito.montaigne.MainActivity) but the popup doesn't recognize it and wont't let me create the new actvity.

Added to that I'm seeing a lot of "cannot resolve symbol" errors in the MainActivity class file. I'm not sure that these errors are having any material difference on the build (though I can't be really sure, as I'm a total noob), but i feel like I have to resolve these issues first before i can fix the real issue I'm having.

I'm using Android Studio 0.26 on MacOS X 10.8.4.

any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did an update to 0.26 and had the same problem. CLosing the project, and restarting Android studio and then opening the project seems to have cleared whatever it was that was causing this.

Answer (score 0):

so, it turns out that Studio is (understandibly) buggy, and that these errors are false negatives...

I can also add the hierarchical parent by hand in the code so the question about the popup is moot too :/