# android studio cannot find "Activity" symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried to create and run `hello world` new app using `Android studio.`
however i cannot compile as it says it's cannot resolve `Activity` symbol.

and also other basic symbols in the black template.

I suggest adding/configuration the JDK.

I guess I'm doing this wrong, because I have tried to add the `JDK` and the problem re-occurred.

[image]

how to solve this?

**UPDATE1**

couldn't find external build

[image]

[image]

Android studio 0.2.6

Comment: a restart, clean and re-uild solve the issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563026/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-xxx-on-basic-android-tutorial

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Android Studio

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

It Worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to import android.app.Activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem as well and it was driving me crazy.  Here is what worked for me:

I noticed that Under File|Project Structure the Classpath for my selected android SDK (Android 4.3 Google APIs) was blank.

I changed the Build target to a different SDK, then switched back and the Classpath tab became properly populated.  Once I did that, android symbols were resolved in my project.

If you don't see pathtosdk/android-##/android.jar listed in the classpath, this could be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As addition, if all solutions you have tried getting no result, in my case, make sure your activity already defined on `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
   android:name=".Main2Activity"
   ...
></activity>
```

This happens when I create activity manually by creating Activity Class **directly** without building from template **(right click -> new -> activity -> Empty Activity/other templates )**.

Answer (score 0):

i changed my module version in file -> project structure, to last version i've downloaded